# How to fix Heroku Dyno not showing up?

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

Ok so, I am trying to make a Discord.py bot. I did, but now I can't host it. When I try (on Heroku) the dyno never shows up. This is the GitHub Link: https://github.com/EchoNoahGaming/echobot/

I expected it to have a Dyno, but it didn't.

The Procfile only has "worker: pybot.py" in it, and inside of the logs it says

```
2019-04-07T17:07:09.025914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=echobotyeet.herokuapp.com request_id=1330f84d-51a4-4462-9de1-cbea09bc621b fwd="172.6.17.203" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-07T17:07:11.185818+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=echobotyeet.herokuapp.com request_id=93b077ec-61de-4e5f-b7e3-e9e2a0674546 fwd="172.6.17.203" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
```

some of the main bot is

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.command()
async def announcement(ctx, *, args):
    """Announcement command!"""
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Announcement", description=args, color=0x7700aa)
    embed.set_footer(text="By EchoNoahGaming")
    await ctx.send("@everyone", embed=embed)

client.run(str(os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')))
```

Comment: Do you get any error or log?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions must be self-contained; we're not going to go off-site to dig through your code and find problems. Please [edit] your question and add your `Procfile` as well as a reasonable part of your main script. Ideally, we'd like to see a [mcve].

Comment: Well that's your first problem. You're only defining a worker. Heroku hosts _web_ applications. Does `pybot.py` spawn a web server and listen for HTTP requests? (You haven't included any part of your main script like I requested. And those two log entries are irrelevant.)

Comment: i'm only defining a worker because I am following a tutorial that did that and worked for them

Comment: Do you expect your `pybot.py` to receive HTTP requests from outside of Heroku? If so, it should be a `web` process. If not, have you [scaled your worker up](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#scaling-a-process-type)?

Comment: I don't know what scaled your worker up means, I just followed a tutorial bro

Comment: ...did you bother following the link I thoughtfully provided? It provides a lot of detail about scaling processes. And please don't call me "bro".

Comment: the person that made it said everything was fine so I posted on here

Comment: _**Again**, did you **follow the link I provided?** Did you try **scaling your worker up?**_ We can't help you if you refuse to cooperate.

Comment: I don't know where to input the commands. If it's Git, I can't

Comment: I'm using Github not Heroku Git

Comment: @EchoNoahGaming, that command has _nothing at all_ to do with Git. GitHub, Heroku Git, GitLab, or anything else; it's all irrelevant. That's the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli). Have you installed it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Procfile` is not defined correctly, change it `worker: pybot.py` to `-->` `worker: python pybot.py`

Also in your `requirements.txt` it should only be names of modulo that are not installed as a default with Python and ones that you'll be needing.